# Excel | Searching table in different sheet and bringing value from column in that row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

I am trying to lookup a table in one of my sheets. my table consists of three columns and an unlimited amount of rows.

My table can be seen here:

[image]

In my second sheet I wish to write a formula which searches all rows in the table and looks for an exact match in column A and column B, this means it must find the row where column a has a value of "jan" and in that same row the second column must have value "y". Should it find this match, it should return the value of column C.

I tried researching hlookup but that is for horizontal tables so i dont believe this would work. I looked into Vlookups also but that only allows one criteria search instead of looking for two matches.

Can anyone shed some light here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index and match with multiple criteria

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1000, MATCH("Jan"&"y", $A$1:$A$1000&$B$1:$B$1000, 0),3)
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when entering this formula.

Comment: I need it to find the row in which the month is jan and product is x, once it finds that row, it should return the value of the alteration column (column c). your example returns "jan" for some reason

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put ,3) at the end to get the value from column 3 of the range.  I din't test it so it's amazing that it returned anything ;)

Comment: Another edit, I had the index range only looking at column A so i've updated it to go to column C.

Comment: this returned a #ref message. I will be forever in your debt if you could please test this for me. here is my current sheet layout (the table in the right looks for the product in the respective month and prints the alteration  the correct value for g10 is 49-- https://gyazo.com/c72dbca5b944ed8feec524e8c65588f6

Comment: Our comments crossed.  I changed $A$1:$A$1000 -> $A$1:$C$1000 and tested that it works ok now.

Comment: No problem.  You can mark it as the accepted answer if it's doing what you need it to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `INDEX` function has the syntax

```
INDEX(array, row_num_in_array, [column_num_in_array])
```

And `MATCH` returns in the index location of a logic match

```
MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
```

Combining the two is a flexible technique, and surprisingly powerful -- the logic in a match lookup_value can be a complex condition.

#### SIMPLEST CODE

Operate on the whole column

```
INDEX(C:C, MATCH("Jan"&"y", A:A&B:B, 0), 1)
```

nb./ `A:A` is excel code for "all of column A".  You can instead use:

#### RESTRICTED CODE

Operates on a subset of the sheet.

```
INDEX($C$2:$C$1000, MATCH("Jan"&"y", $A$2:$A$1000&$B$2:$B$1000, 0), 1)
```

Note that you MUST use identical row length arrays (eg. rows 2:1000) or the formula will not work. `MATCH` only knows how many rows into its lookup_array it got, you need to ensure its rows match those in `INDEX`'s  array

PS. apologies this is close to the previous answer, but the details were too long for a comment.

PPS. I missed the clarifications to the first answer.  That will work, but there is no need to use all three columns as the `array` in the `INDEX` function.  You are only returning data from column C after all.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the range to a table (ctrl-t) and then use SUMIFS to search the table based on two criteria

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[Alteration],Table1[Month],"Jan",Table1[Products],"y")
```

This is saying "give me [Alteration] where [Month] = "Jan" and [Products] = 'y'...this returns 364.

You can point the criteria at separate cells containing your criteria.

Be aware that if there is more than one row with identical data (ie more than one row with both 'Jan' and 'y'), column C will be summed together.